# How to get value of field from json on bash

Tags: bash

I want to get the value of my field from the my environments

```
environments
System-Provided:
{
 "VCAP_SERVICES": {
     "mySerivce" : {
       "url" :"myValue"
      },
      "mySerivce2" : {
       "url" :"myValue2"
      }
  }
}
```

I want to get the value of url from
System-Provided -> "VCAP_SERVICES"->  "mySerivce2" ->

I tried

```
cf env myApp| grep url| cut -d ':' -f2)"
```

bu then I got two results from all the services
How I can get result only from one service ?
also there are many fields in each service

Comment: `url=$(jq -r '.VCAP_SERVICES.myService.url' <in.json)`

Comment: do I need to install jq ?

Comment: can I do it without jq ?

Comment: You could use Python instead (it's not hard to just have one shell function that starts a Python interpreter inside a larger shell script). You still need *something* with a real JSON parser. The linked-duplicate question has answers covering several other options.

Comment: `url=$(python -c "import sys, json; print(json.load(sys.stdin)['VCAP_SERVICES']['myService']['url'])" <in.json)`, to adopt from the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/1955555/14122